# How to define and set TextView in a for loop to concise the code?

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I want to make the below code concise. It has repetition of similar kind of calls. I tried LinearView and GetChildCount method but It does not give me proper results, I might have misunderstood how to define these in loop using Childs Or other method.

Can any one help ?

```
tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
// ...
// ... and so on till
// ...
tv25 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv25);

// Similarly
tv1.setText(stall);
// ... till ...
tv25.setText(stall);
```

Comment: Please don't forget to tag your language! You're very unlikely to get any responses otherwise...

Comment: I'm assuming it's javascript?

Comment: Yes,Its Android

Comment: you should take a look into Data Binding Library [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    //create an array of ids
    int[] editextIDs = {R.id.tv1
            ,R.id.tv2
            ,R.id.tv3
            ,R.id.tv4
            ,R.id.tv5
            ,R.id.tv6
            ,R.id.tv7
            ,R.id.tv8
            ,R.id.tv9
            ,R.id.tv10
            ,R.id.tv11
            ,R.id.tv12
            ,R.id.tv13
            ,R.id.tv14
            ,R.id.tv15
            ,R.id.tv16
            ,R.id.tv17
            ,R.id.tv18
            ,R.id.tv19
            ,R.id.tv20
            ,R.id.tv21
            ,R.id.tv22
            ,R.id.tv23
            ,R.id.tv24
            ,R.id.tv25
    };
    //create an arraylist of 25 editTexts
    ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    //fill the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 25 ;i++)
    {
        editTexts.add(i,(EditText) findViewById(editextIDs[i]));
    }
    //set the texts
    for(int i = 25; i <25 ;i++)
    {
        editTexts.get(i).setText(stall);
    }
```

This may seem a lot of cut and pasting, but i created the ,R.id.tvX with excel. To do this, you write

> ,R.id.tv1

and then drag it till you got 25 fields.

Also, if you want to clean your code a bit, you may create a class in which you paste the array creation part and make the variable static. For example if you call the class EditTextArrayHandler, you would get the array like this:

```
int[] editextIDs = EditTextArrayHandler.editTextIDs;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know !

Comment: You may want to look at the post linked in the comments. This is just about the same code needed as the original question

Comment: @Frantisek Hlinka  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using Java reflections can dramatically decrease your code

```
EditText[] tv_ar = new EditText[25];
for (int i = 0; i < et_ar.length; i++) {
    int cur_tv_index = R.id.class.getField("tv" + Integer.toString(i+1)).getInt(null);
    tv_ar[i] = (EditText) findViewById(cur_tv_index);
}
```

It is possible to use

`int cur_tv_index=context.getResources().getIdentifier("tv" + Integer.toString(i+1), "id", context.getPackageName());`

Comment: What's wrong with `Resources.getIdentifier()`?

Comment: Nothing. I just have not tested it. I think, at least, there is a `Context` depend. It makes no sense in common Android programming.

Comment: Makes no sense? An Activity is a Context. There is also `getApplicationContext()`, so I don't understand that comment

Comment: 'It makes no sense' - I meant namely you wrote: ' An Activity is a Context. There is also `getApplicationContext()`, so I don't understand that comment'. You are totally right.

Comment: I'm just making the point that using a Context is very common in most applications that I have seen.